# Webauthn AuthenticatorAttestationResponse "getPublicKey" returns a restricted object?

Tags: javascript, webauthn, passkey

I'm trying to implement passkeys for my web app according to [these](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2022/09/22/passkeys.html) [guides](https://web.dev/articles/passkey-registration), and I'm primarily working on the registration flow. After I've created the passkey using `navigator.credential.create`, I try obtaining the newly generated public key using the `getPublicKey` method on the returned response attribute. However, when I try inspecting the object, my browser says:

```js
Restricted { }
```

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AuthenticatorAttestationResponse/getPublicKey), this object should be an ArrayBuffer. In order to send it to the server I try to convert it to a base64-encoded string, however whenever I try to do something with this (in fact, whenever I try to do *anything* to it), the browser throws an error saying I can't access this object.

I've already worked around this by sending the `attestationObject` to the server and having the server decode it, but according to everything I've read, I should be able to do this client-side. Am I missing something obvious, or is this expected behavior?